# How to pass system date and time to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008

I want to get the system date and time using my `C#` program and pass it in to database. I used DateTime data type in `SQL Server` table.

I used `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;` method to get system date and time. but i passed it into database i got following error.

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

How to solve this error.

Table structure -

```
create table Candidates_ElecCenter(
  Cand_ID varchar(10) primary key, 
  Party_ID varchar(3),
  Name varchar(100),
  NIC varchar(50),
  DistrictID varchar(3) ,
  seat varchar(50) ,
  Total_Votes int,
  year datetime default  DATENAME(year, GETDATE())  ,
  Candidate_Type int , 
  CONSTRAINT fk_CandDistrict FOREIGN KEY (DistrictID) REFERENCES District(District_ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Cand_year_Election FOREIGN KEY (year) REFERENCES Election(year),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Non_Ind_Party_ID_cand FOREIGN KEY (Party_ID) REFERENCES NonIndependent_Poll_Party(Party_ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Ind_Party_ID_cand FOREIGN KEY (Party_ID) REFERENCES Independent_Poll_Party(Party_ID),
);
```

Function:

```
internal bool InsertDetails(string p, string p_2, string p_3, string p_4, string p_5, string p_6, int sts)
{
    bool status = false;

    if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
    {
        conn.Open();
    }

    SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    newCmd.Connection = conn;
    newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    newCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Candidates_ElecCenter(Cand_ID,Party_ID,Name,NIC,DistrictID,seat,year,Candidate_Type) VALUES ('" + p + "','" + p_2 + "','" + p_3 + "' ,'" + p_4 + "', '" + p_5 + "', '" + p_6 + "', '" + now + "','" + sts + "')";

    newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
    status = true;

    return status;
}
```

Comment: How did you *try* to pass it to the database? Please show us some code.

Comment: How are you forming the query?

Comment: Can you show what you're passing the values into?

Comment: In addition to the C# Code you should also post the schema for the table you are inserting the data in to.

Comment: The down votes are a bit harsh, I think we all know they're probably concatenating a strings together to form a query and it's a common mistake for newbies.

Comment: One of the String fields (the p parameters) is almost certainly too long. If you put a breakpoint on the code and run it you should find out which. Alternatively use SQL Profiler to watch what you're passing through as you run the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    using(SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
      newCmd.Connection = conn;
      newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

      DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
      newCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Candidates_ElecCenter(Cand_ID,Party_ID,Name,NIC,DistrictID,seat,year,Candidate_Type) VALUES (@Cand_ID,@Party_ID,@Name,@NIC,@DistrictID,@seat,@year,@Candidate_Type)";

      newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cand_ID", p);
      newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Party_ID", p_2);
      newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", p_3);
      newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIC", p_4);
      newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DistrictID", p_5);
      newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seat", p_6);
      newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", now);
      newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Candidate_Type", sts);

      newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Concatenating strings together to form a query leaves you at risk of SQL injection attacks, and you don't need to do it.
Also, wrap your connection in a "using" if you can as well, then you don't need to worry about closing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter( "@news_date", SqlDbType.DateTime );  
param2.Value = DateTime.Today;  
command.Parameters.Add( param2 );
```

Does that help?

Comment: He's probably after DateTime.Now.